# Two gedit plugins clash. How to change shortcut keys, or enable/disable a plugin

Tags: command-line, python, gedit, plugins, gconf

Gedit has two plugins from [Gnome's Gedit Plugins page](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins) which I both particularly want...

- [Multi-edit](http://jon-walsh.com/journal/multi-edit/)
- [Control Your Tabs](http://www.thingsthemselves.com/gedit/)

However they both vie for the same shortcut keys: Ctrl+PageUp and Ctrl+PageDown

I can see two possible solutions, and maybe there are more,,,(there usually is :)

The best solution may be to change the shorcut keys in Multi-edit to Shift+Ctrl+PageUp and Shift+Ctrl+PageDown... but I've very little python knowledge, and how to do it escapes me..

The simplest method (for me) is to just toggle them on/off via another shortcut-key. I know the command to toggle the Multi-edit feature on/off (but not the entire script)...  Basically, for this option, I need a command to toggle a Gedit Plugin on/off..

Either, or both (,or other) solutions would be appreciated...

**UPDATE**: I'm looking for a *command-line* command (vs, a menu command),
and/or a 'fix' for Multi-edit's python script.

Note: The  'Edit Shortcuts' plugin does not show the Multi-edit plugin... (so I can't do it that way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote the following python script ([download](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/556656/)) that enables/disables the Multi-edit plugin:

```
#!/usr/env/python

import re
import commands

active_plugins = commands.getoutput("gconftool --get /apps/gedit-2/plugins/active-plugins")

r1 = re.compile(r'multi_edit')

if r1.search(active_plugins):
    # Disable multi-edit plugin
    active_plugins = re.sub("multi_edit,|,multi_edit","", active_plugins)

else:
    # Enable multi-edit plugin
    active_plugins = re.sub("]",",multi_edit]", active_plugins)
    
commands.getoutput("gconftool --set --type=list --list-type=string /apps/gedit-2/plugins/active-plugins "+active_plugins)
```

---

To toggle Multi-edit with a keyboard shortcut:

1. Save the script as `toggle-multi-edit.py` in your home folder.
2. Open up *System → Preferences → Keyboard Shortcuts*. Click *Add* and put `python /home/<user>/toggle-multi-edit.py` for the *Command*, replacing `<user>` with your actual username.

   [image]

Comment: Thanks DoR.. I've been busy myself and came back to the page to post my bash script :)..  I'm very keen to see your python script.. but for now I'll just post mine..(need a break..It's been an all-nighter.) ...

Comment: It's good...Thanks.... Python has a simplicity I like, but unfortunately it isn't simple to me (yet) :)... I'll stay focused on bash for a while longer, to try to get a decent intial understanding of it.. then I'll look further into python...  (I've tried to give you a +1 but it says I marked you 2 hours ago.. I recall I did give you a +1, then I retracted it until I could have a good look at the answer...Now it says I can't change anything until the answer is modified/edited..

Comment: @fred.bear I made a tiny edit so you can vote now ;)

Answer (score 2):

Its simple :)

**Enabling**

1. Edit > Preferences
2. Now look at the **Plugins** section.
3. Select the check box next to the name of the plugin that you want to enable.
4. You may now Click **Close** to close Gedit, Then start it again

**Disabling**

1. Edit > Preferences
2. Now look at the **Plugins** section.
3. Deselect the check box next to the name of the plugin that you want to enable.
4. You may now Click **Close** to close Gedit, Then start it again

Comment: Thanks Michael.. I seem to have not made it clear.. I assumed tht everyone sees the word "command" as I do... but they don't...  I meant a command-line command (and you thought:  menu command) .. I must ammende my question.. (+1.. you have presented a very clear answer)

Answer (score 2):

After finally finding a reference to gedit's plugins, I've put together a bash script...

Because this script is exclusive to gedit, adding it via gedit's External Tools localizes the scope of your choice of shortcut key to gedit only.. I'm using Ctrl+NumPad7 (because it is very close to PageUp and PageDown)...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Toggle gedit plugin ControlYourTabs  ON/OFF, with inverse switching for   
# Multi-Edit's "Columns Always Available" feature, which uses same shortcuts 
# ==========================================================================
cytab=controlyourtabs
plugins=$(gconftool-2 --get /apps/gedit-2/plugins/active-plugins)
#
if [[ "$plugins" =~ ^\[(.+,)*$cytab(,.+)*\]$ ]] ; then
    #
    # "Control Your Tabs" found in list... Disable it
    #  and enable "Multi Edit - Columns Always Available"  
    #
    if   [[ "$plugins" =~ ^.+\,$cytab(,.+)*\]$ ]] ; then plugins=${plugins/,${cytab}/}
    elif [[ "$plugins" =~   ^\[$cytab\,.+$     ]] ; then plugins=${plugins/${cytab},/}
    elif [[ "$plugins" =~   ^\[$cytab\]$       ]] ; then plugins=[]
    else echo "Logic Error in one of the regex patterns"; exit 1
    fi
    multi=true
else
    # "Control Your Tabs" NOT found in list... Enable it
    #  and disable "Multi Edit - Columns Always Available"  
    #
    plugins=${plugins%]},$cytab]
    multi=false
fi
#
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gedit-2/plugins/active-plugins --type=list --list-type=string "$plugins"
gconftool-2 --set /apps/gedit-2/plugins/multi_edit/columns_always_avail --type bool  $multi
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I was / am navigating this with [regex](https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/gedit-re-search/wiki/Home) and [ipython](http://www.cogsci.nl/software/gedit-ipython-plugin) plugins, that both want to run on <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>. I sniffed around in "regexsearchinstance.py" (in `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/regex_replace`) and found this:

```
def create_menu_item(self):
        """
        Create a menu item in the "Tools" menu.
        """
        action = gtk.Action("RegexSearch", 
                _("Regular expression..."), 
                _("Search using regular expressions"), None)
        action.connect("activate", self.on_open_regex_dialog)

        action_group = gtk.ActionGroup("RegexSearchActions")
        action_group.add_action_with_accel(action, "<control>r")

        manager = self._window.get_ui_manager()
        manager.insert_action_group(action_group, -1)
        manager.add_ui_from_string(ui_str)
```

I changed one line to:

```
action_group.add_action_with_accel(action, "<control><shift>f")
```

and quit gedit. Now regex searches load on <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shfit</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>. I see a comparable line in `/usr/lib/gedit/plugins/ipython.py`:

```
self._action_group.add_actions([('IPython', None,
        _('Run in IPython'), '<Control>r', _('Clear the document'),
        self.send_to_ipython)])
```

So if you want to actually edit the plugins so that they use different shortcuts by default, sniff around for `<Control>` or `<control>` or `add_action` in the plugin file.